# Regular Expression in Serialized Data

Tags: php, regex, symfony, serialization, doctrine

I am looking to a database search on serialized data. I am currently using Symfony2 as my Framework making pdo_mysql calls using Doctrine 2. What I would like to do is create a query that uses REGEXP to find data within a certian part of the array. The data I am trying to search within looks like this: -

```
a:1:{s:8:"bedrooms";a:5:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;s:2:"5+";}}
```

So let's say I am looking for a record that has 3 bedrooms, then I would want it to find: -

```
i:2;i:3
```

The query I have come up with so far is: -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name REGEXP '.*"bedrooms"; a:[0-9]+:{i:[0-9]+;i:3;}.*';
```

However this doesn't work. Can someone help me find a fix around this please? I think it's down to the way the regular expression is written.

Also its worth noting that there are other arrays stored in the field such credit limits and other data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about not serializing it in the first place?

Comment: This isn't the only data stored in the serialized data. There are many more parameters that are also being stored and thats why I used serialized data.

Comment: If you never *ever* plan to query on it, by all means serialize the hell out of it. However, if you *might* ever want to query *anything* in a *sane* manner you should not serialize it. This looks like it might be MLS data, and I get that RETS data is a bag of cats, but SQL is a very poor choice for storing denormalized data.

Comment: I get where your coming from but to be honest, all I wanted was a solution to my problem. Ever since the data was serialized my query times have dropped and with thanks to Wiktor's help it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do it with the help of negated character class `[^{}]` that matches *any character but a `{` and `}`*:

```
.*"bedrooms";a:[0-9]+:[{][^{}]*i:[0-9]+;i:3[^{}]*[}]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW8oL2/1)

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 mistakes and improvements you can do

- first, in regex drop the blank space after `"bedrooms";`
- you should scape the curly braces like `\{` and `\}` since they are not literal for regex engine
- if you are interested in a specific chunk in the string you must specify it as a group and inform what kind of characters are around, like

  "bedrooms";a:[0-9]+:\{.*(i:[0-9];i:3).*\}

In this case in looking for `i:*:i:3` where * is any digit

Comment: Thank you for your comment Omar. This looks great and I will try this out.